# ORA-01033: ORACLE initialization or shutdown in progress database 12c error

Tags: sql, database, oracle

It was all ok before and my project was working.Today I have tried to start it, but recieved this error.
After that I've tried to use the response to run sqlplus

> sqlplus /nolog

```
SQL> connect / as sysdba
```

But after this line I've recieved this error:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

I am using oracle 12c database

Answer (score 1):

The answer to main problem ORA-1033:

```
// *Cause: An attempt was made to log on while Oracle is being started up
//         or shutdown.
// *Action: Wait a few minutes. Then retry the operation.
```

The explanation says that, you DB is in either shutdown or startup state.

The error ORA-1017 is expected in Oracle 12c, because starting this release OS authentication `connect / as sysdba` is deprecated. Check this [link](https://dborasol.wordpress.com/2013/10/04/oracle-db-12c-os-authentication-not-support-anymore/) for more details.